# Prevent registration to web scams

Tags: chrome-for-android

I just got a strange SMS claiming that I've registered to some weird service and based on that they took the money from my account. This was proceeded by a popup related to some mobile games while I was browsing. At no point did I register or click enter my information or telephone number.

I'm using Chrome 46.0.2490.76 and Android 4.3.0

Does anybody know what is the general technical background of this fraud and what can be done to prevent it in the future (popup blockers or similar approach?)?

Comment: This largely depends on the carriers (and might be country-specific) – but have you contacted your provider? They might offer to opt-out of "mobile payment" and "value-added services".

Comment: Yes, and they have disable the future registrations. The motivation for the question is to understand on what happened. To know if this mechanism it purely link based? Or it relies on some other means?

Comment: Hard to say. While it mostly relates to some (accidentally) clicked link, malware programmers might have found other means. If you can convince your carrier you didn't "order that service" (so it was fraud), they should cancel it as well. Not sure whether you can force them to, however. The bill should also name the company behind that scan, so you could report that to get it "shot down".

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody know what is the general technical background of this fraud and what can be done to prevent it in the future (popup blockers or similar approach?)?

Android allows you to link javascript to an application. This seems likely the service provider added a "bad browser", check if you have any custom browser on your device, and if the device has any program that enables JS communication ([this link for documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html))

Then again more details are needed to help...

Most likely your browser is a custom one, tampered by the manufacturer (so, post your device Model, as well as build number and source) that "sells" informations... such as getting phone number, re-routing add requests, or even an explicit malware being run in the browser, or in the device.